# Count appearances of two cells in a 5x100 matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two cells that I want to compare against a 5 columns by 100 rows matrix where they can appear.

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
  =COUNTIFS(Winners!$B$2:$F$452,Numbers!$A6,Winners!$B$2:$F$452,Numbers!O$1)
```

Where `Winners!$B$2:$F$452` is the matrix with the winner combinations and `Numbers!$A6` or `Numbers!O$1` are the numbers I am comparing.

Comment: So what result(s) are you hoping to return?

Comment: The amount of time that in that case A6 and O1 appear on the matrix

Comment: I might have it explained myself wrong, A6 and O1 in a row. So it isn't a total count it is the total amount of rows in Winners!$B$2:$F$452 where both A6 and O1 appear. Basically I am trying to get the most common pair in the lottery.

Comment: Ah, ok. Amended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=COUNT(1/(MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(Winners!$B$2:$F$452,ROW(Winners!$B$2:$F$452)-MIN(ROW(Winners!$B$2:$F$452)),,1),CHOOSE({1,2},Numbers!$A6,Numbers!O$1)),{1;1})=2))`

Assumes the values in Numbers!A6 and Numbers!O1 can only ever occur once each in a given row in the range Winners!B2:F452.

Regards